# Как исправить ClassNotFoundException при создании AAR на Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, aar

Написал библиотеку для Android используя Kotlin. Генерирую AAR-файл. При попытке подключить этот AAR к стороннему проекту написанному на Java, приложение падает при запуске с такой ошибкой:

```
Process: ru.bartwell.app, PID: 10412
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;
        at ru.bartwell.mylib.MyLibClass.<init>(MyLibClass.kt)
        at ru.bartwell.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ru.bartwell.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ru.bartwell.app-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at ru.bartwell.mylib.MyLibClass.<init>(MyLibClass.kt) 
        at ru.bartwell.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 15 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Так выглядит Gradle файл в модуле библиотеки:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Вроде дело в том, что зависимости библиотеки не поставляются вместе с `aar` файлом. Т.е. вам надо помимо файла либы ещё и все её зависимости добавить там, где вы либу используете.

Comment: А можете подсказать, как это сделать в моем случае?

Comment: Ну, по идее надо добавить в проект, использующий либу вот это в её `build.gradle` - `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, хм, это действительно работает. Но как-то не кошерно заставлять пользователя подключать котлин всякий раз при использовании либы. Тем более, что его проект может быть реализован на Java. Может быть есть какой-то другой вариант? Например, чтобы либа скомпилилась как Java или как-то все-таки вкомпилить котлин в либу? Неужели обязательно переписывать проект на Java, чтобы пользователь не таскал за собой котлин?

Comment: Ну... Тут всё сложно. С одной стороны, я такого способа в своё время не нашёл. С другой, лиы обычно не файлом распространяются, но ссылкой на публичный репозиторий. Для старой версии `gradle` такой способ позволяет подключить либу одной строкой как зависимость. Но вот с новым `gradle` мне не удалось так либу в репозиторий залить. В общем, если не хотите головняка с новым `gradle` и публикацией либы в публичный репозиторий (несколько дней танцами с бубном точно угробите) то заставляйте юзеров указывать зависимости вручную.

Answer (score 1):

В `aar` по-умолчанию не включаются зависимости. Для копирования всех зависимостей в результирующий `aar` можно написать следующий gradle-таск:

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

И запускать его перед публикацией артефакта в репозиторий командой `./gradlew copyLibs`.